# How to link Jenkins build information with JIRA issue

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, bamboo, jira-rest-api

I am looking for an API to add build information to JIRA issues. My CI is Jenkins.
I would assume it would behave in the same manner as [Bamboo builds](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamkb/bamboo-build-information-is-missing-under-builds-tab-in-jira-653951219.html)

I have been searching in here:

- https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/
- https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.6.1/
- https://jenkinsci.github.io/jira-steps-plugin/

and I haven't found anything. Is this feature reserved for Bamboo?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install jira plugin and that will enable you to use JIRA REST API.

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/JIRA+Plugin

Comment: There is no API for builds apparently. It is reserved for Bamboo.

Comment: @Fishman this is an old post but I think now there is... I want to achieve the same thing (but link build info to jira) but also deployment info.

[api for build](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/software/modules/build/)  || 
[api for deployment](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/software/modules/deployment/)

Comment: Still I like to figure out how.. I have commit ID(s) but not sure how to hook that up to the API -> not really clearly documented. What I need is probably the issue-keys

Comment: @VDP: Usually that information is taken from one of the following:
* commit message,
* branch name,
* Pull Request title

Comment: @VDP: There is more about how to construct request under https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/software/rest/#api-builds-0-1-bulk-post

Comment: @Fishman making a request is easy, I was struggling a bit with understanding what they mean by all the properties you can send. And also yes I figured it was coming from commit message, branch name, pr title. So I need to cook up something myself. Since Jira knows I hoped it would be able to do that for me..

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to fool JIRA into thinking it's talking to Bamboo, and as a result have it displaying build statuses from my own hardcoded files.

If there's any interest i'll post the code up to github

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).