# Add build and deployment info to JIRA

Tags: teamcity, jira, jira-rest-api

Our setup is:

- JIRA (ticket management)
- bitbucket (repo)
- teamcity (ci)
- aws k8s (deployment)

The build & deployment tools aren't that important in this case, just that it isn't Bamboo..

In bamboo I've seen it working that it shows build info & deployment info on the ticket.

[image]

I see that there is a JIRA-api

- [Build API](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/software/modules/build/)
- [Deployment API](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/software/modules/deployment/)

I just don't understand how I can go from the commit id and hook that up in this api request.
I see `"key": "build-integration"` or `"key": "deployment-integration"`.

- What does that mean?
- And how can the commit id be linked to the ticket?
- Is that something jira can do automagically? (Jira can show the right branches and commits from bitbucket on the tickes so jira is smart enough there...)

PS: I only came across [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48221453/how-to-link-jenkins-build-information-with-jira-issue) saying it isn't possible due to no API but seems now there is one.. Just not so clear..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [paid plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1210766/teamcity-integration-for-jira?hosting=cloud&tab=overview) which can show build / deployment info from TeamCity against a Jira ticket. The link is whenever a commit message contains a Jira ticket id is included in a TeamCity build.

---

Update: TeamCity 2020.1 has now added support for [displaying TeamCity build information in Jira Cloud](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/what-s-new-in-teamcity-2020-1.html#WhatsNewinTeamCity2020.1-DisplayingTeamCitybuildinformationinJiraCloud)

Comment: I marked it as answer because. What I said in the question to be 'build api' or 'deployment api' is actually not the api but a module. And if I understand correctly a module seems to be something that can only be used in an 'app/plugin' like the one for TeamCity here. I checked, there is one for Jenkins, CircleCi, ... Don't think I'm gonna bother try to write a plugin to do my own stuff..

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [Smart Commits](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiracloud/enable-smart-commits-776830276.html). This basically links your git repository to a JIRA project, and allows to trigger actions from JIRA such as create branches and raise merge requests.

You can then use git commits to update your JIRA tickets - see the below as an example of what you can do on JIRA with a commit:

`git commit -m "$PrjKey-$TicketId #time 2h #comment This is a comment."`

The `$PrjKey-$TicketId` links the commit to the project and ticket.

The rest it is optional and there are [several other actions](https://confluence.atlassian.com/fisheye/using-smart-commits-960155400.html) that can be taken, including updating several tickets with a single commit.

Comment: While it is really interesting, it's not 100% what I was looking for. The goal is to see what is build & what is deployed. It already shows: branches, pull requests and commits. But 
 it's interesting, you got my vote! I'll read up on it a bit more. Thanks!

Comment: I think you can only achieve what you see on the screenshot(build + deployment on JIRA development panel) if you are using bitbucket + bamboo. If you find another way let me know :)